# EXTERNAL_QUERY suddenly started to return BYTE value instead of STRING

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using Query which joins external data through `EXTERNAL_QUERY()` LIKE THIS
(this is just example, not actual one)

```sql
SELECT 
    ext.program_id,
    SUM(price) AS total_price
FROM a_dataset.purchases pcs
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
         program_id, 
         version 
    FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY(
        'CONNECTION_INFO',
        'SELECT program_id, version FROM products'
    )
) ext ON pcs.program_id = ext.program_id
```

This query actually worked at my environment.
However, from today, this part ↓

```
EXTERNAL_QUERY(
        'CONNECTION_INFO',
        'SELECT program_id, version FROM products'
    )
```

starts to return byte value which looks like encrypted and
turns out to show this message

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, BYTES. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [37:9]
```

`'CONNECTION_INFO'` refers Cloud SQL, read replica instance of MySQL.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this, or why these return values started to changed ?

Comment: i would use some `cast(program_id as string)`s to ensure you have the same datatypes

Comment: Thank you for your comment. yes, that what I finally found as a work around. That works. I'm still wondering why this change has happened...